# Question mark inside XML file without encoding produces errors while trying to load it

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to load an xml file into an xmlDocument object..the problem is that it says "invalid character in the giving encoding"..which is correct, because the defition of the xml file I have as an input says only `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`, and no encoding is specified..

The question mark is an actual question mark. I made a little utility to search through the document and find the character that is giving the trouble, when I find it and display it on a label, it is a question mark surrounded by a black box..

What I am asking is, I still need to load this file and analyze it, any help on how to do it?

Any configuration of my xmlDocument object that I must specify ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hang on, is this question mark actually a question mark? Or is it a unicode character that isn't being displayed? Basically, are you saying that this XML is genuinely invalid (due to the `xml` declaration not matching the encoding of the file) but you need to parse it anyway?

Comment: The question mark is an actual question mark. I made a little utility to search through the document and find the character that is giving the trouble, when I find it and display it on a label, it is a question mark surrounded by a black box..

Comment: No specified encoding defaults to utf-8. The character in question is most certainly not a question mark. Try loading the file in to a hex editor to find the actual byte sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this worked :

```
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(TxtPath.Text, true);

            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(sr);
```

This loads the document as unicode and fixes the problem with strange characters in a non formatted xml file